# Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation when MockDispatcher used with FlowDocument

Tags: c#, wpf

1. I am testing function `SaveToFile` from unit tests.
2. Unfortunately I got error related to dispated. Therefore I isolated my `Dispatcher` and prepared `MockDispatcher` that I am injecting in Unit Tests.
3. This is my mock dispatcher which I inject:

   ```
   public class MockDispatcher : IDispatcher 
   {
       public void BeginInvoke(Action method, params object[] args)
       {
           method.DynamicInvoke(args);
       }

       public void Invoke(Action method, params object[] args)
       {
           method.Invoke();
       } 
   }
   ```
4. This is my function which I test:

   ```
   public bool SaveToFile(string filePath)
   {    
       bool result = false;    
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
       {
           var document = GetFlowDocument(new List<Log>(Logs));
           result = _fileService.SaveTextRangeToRtf(new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd), filePath);

           });    
       return result;
   }

   private FlowDocument GetFlowDocument(IEnumerable<Log> Logs) 
   {
       var document = new FlowDocument();
       var paragraph = new Paragraph();

       foreach (var item in Logs)
       {
           paragraph.Inlines.AddRange(_converter.ConvertToInlines(item));
       }

       document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

       return document;
   }
   ```
5. I receive following exception in unit tests:

   `Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.`
6. In UI mode it works properly.